# Ordering Test Cases in Azure-Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, testcase

The new version of Azure-DevOps no longer allows me to order Test Cases within a Test Suite. Previously there was an 'Order tests' button on the top of the view. Does anyone know how I do this in the new version, please?

[image: Old version showing Order tests button]

Answer (score 0):

In ADO Test plans

Go to any Suite --->In Define tab-->Click order any number of times you want to sort it or order by .

You can See the icon [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npYsA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can click and drag the test cases in the Define tab to reorder them. It's not very discoverable, but it works just fine. Then you can sort by order as the first answer describes.

Answer (score 0):

just select the row in define, and move it to the place you want:
[image]